# Is it ok to use long-lived Tasks that aren't long-running Tasks?

Tags: .net, async-await, task, task-parallel-library, threadpool

For example, if I had to choose between these two, should I dedicate a `Thread` to a periodic cleanup task, or should I just use a looping `Task` that never finishes?

Because the `Thread` would be sleeping most of the time, only occasionally *waking up to a signal* (not necessarily at any particular time) to do a tiny bit of cleanup, I feel that the thread would be wasted. One thread may be no big deal, but I'll potentially have dozens of these.

Instead of creating a dedicated `Thread` that's usually asleep and consuming resources, I would like to use a `Task` that loops forever, waiting (asynchronously) on a 'wake' signal during each iteration.

This wouldn't be a "long-running" Task (i.e. it would not be CPU-bound for very long), but it would be a "long-lived" Task (i.e. it never completes and will typically just be tracked in some await queue).

Suppose I start many of these "long-lived" Tasks. Will I run into any performance problems with this approach as a result of these long-lived Tasks simply existing? It seems simpler to manage the work with Tasks and let them run on ThreadPool threads. The work doesn't need any special priority over other work that might also run on ThreadPool threads.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use either.

> sleeping most of the time, only occasionally waking up to a signal to do a tiny bit of cleanup

This seems like the perfect use case for a [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/timers). While the time is ticking, nothing exists (neither a thread nor a task). When the time elapses, the event handler is run a ThreadPool thread.

Comment: _When the time elapses, the event handler is run on its own thread._  
This is not correct.  The event handlers are run on the ThreadPool.

Comment: @Nick The difference is so subtle that it doesn't matter. But I'll update my answer to use the terminology that the docs use.

Comment: but it does.  If the job he will be doing on the timer tick takes a long, more than just a few seconds, he will be putting exhausting the pool.

Comment: @Nick Yes, that can happen, and I have faced that myself. But the purpose of my answer is only to point in the right direction, not to provide a complete solution that takes into account every variable that could happen. The question said "tiny bit of cleanup", so that's unlikely to be an issue here. If it does end up being an issue, the OP is free to ask for more help.

Comment: That wasn't at all what I'm asking. I'm asking specifically about the performance impacts of using a long-lived Task, which is not a long-running Task.  This was just a concrete example.

Comment: @Triynko Yes, I realize this isn't what you were asking. But this is kind of like asking whether a screwdriver or a chisel would be better for hammering a nail :) Timers were made for exactly the use case you describe and will perform better and be simpler to implement than both solutions you're asking about.

Comment: No, I'm really, truly, not asking what you're answering. I'm asking about the performance impact of having long-lived Tasks in the task parallel library. What impact does having multiple (unfinished) tasks have that persist over time, while other tasks are starting/completing around them. This is not not a time-based cycle, so a timer is not appropriate anyway. The task parallel library has queues of tasks, and work-stealing queues, and unfinished Tasks set on these queues. This is a question about a very specific usage-pattern, similar to, but very different from a well-known anti-pattern.